# How to split calculator logic into its own class? (using Xcode/Swift 11.3.1)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, class, calculator

I built a simple iOS calculator using Xcode it was one view controller and one class, ***I have to put the calculator logic into a separate class*** but I'm not sure how to go about it. Do I create a new class inside the original class or outside of it? The original class had `@IBAction func numberPressed` and a `@IBAction func operandPressed`

How do I pass the input into the new `Calculator` class that I need to create?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var lblDisplay: UILabel!

    var numberOnDisplay: Double = 0
    var previousNumber: Double = 0
    var operand = 0
    var isPerformingOperand = false


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        lblDisplay.text = ""
    }

    // Inputs whatever number is pressed 0-9
    @IBAction func numberPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        let tag = (sender as! UIButton).tag

        if isPerformingOperand == true {
            isPerformingOperand = false
            lblDisplay.text = String(tag)
            numberOnDisplay = Double(lblDisplay.text!)!

        } else {

                lblDisplay.text = lblDisplay.text! + String(tag)
                numberOnDisplay = Double(lblDisplay.text!)!
        }

    }

    // Performs the operands including decimal, clear and backspace
    @IBAction func operandPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        let tag = (sender as! UIButton).tag


        /* Operands:  = (99), . (10) X (12), ÷ (13), - (14), + (15) */

        if tag == 10 {
            if lblDisplay.text?.range(of: ".") == nil {
                lblDisplay.text! += "."
            }
        }

            if tag == 12 {
            isPerformingOperand = true
            previousNumber = Double(lblDisplay.text!)!
            lblDisplay.text = "*"
            operand = tag

        } else if tag == 13 {
            isPerformingOperand = true
            previousNumber = Double(lblDisplay.text!)!
            lblDisplay.text = "÷"
            operand = tag

        } else if tag == 14 {
            isPerformingOperand = true
            previousNumber = Double(lblDisplay.text!)!
            lblDisplay.text = "-"
            operand = tag

        } else if tag == 15 {
            isPerformingOperand = true
            previousNumber = Double(lblDisplay.text!)!
            lblDisplay.text = "+"
            operand = tag
        }
         else if tag == 16 {
                if lblDisplay.text != "" {
                    lblDisplay.text?.removeLast();
                }
        }

        /* clear button tab17 */
        else if tag == 17 {
            lblDisplay.text = ""
            previousNumber = 0
            numberOnDisplay = 0
            operand = 0
        }




        else if tag == 99 {
            /*   = / + -   */
            // operand tag

            if operand == 12 {
            lblDisplay.text = String(previousNumber * numberOnDisplay)

            } else if operand == 13 {
            lblDisplay.text = String(previousNumber / numberOnDisplay)

            } else if operand == 14 {
            lblDisplay.text = String(previousNumber - numberOnDisplay)

            } else if operand == 15 {
            lblDisplay.text = String(previousNumber + numberOnDisplay)
            }
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: “how do I pass the input into the new 'calculator logic class' that i need to create?” The same way you pass anything anywhere. Call a method.

Comment: Start by removing tags. You don't have to use only one method to handle all your button clicks. Your operand should be an `enum`.

Comment: What you want to take in another class ?

Comment: @NajeeburRehman I need to move the calculator logic into a separate class. I believe I need to move the math operators (x, /, +, - etc.) and the clear to a seperate class. It's an assignment and I really dont know how best to proceed based on how I originally coded it.

Comment: See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLKI1wCYln_U2B9B7UqUnj0jj4APBdEntr) from the Stanford course. The programming starts about 17 minutes in, but the lead in discussion is useful.

Comment: Lecture 2 has the discussion on the CalculatorBrain.

Comment: If you want just to separate the calculator logic, create a class named Calculator(or as per your choice) and put all that variables that you have created in  view controller in that Calculator class. Then in your view controller create a private instance of calculator and update the variables according to your logic. But atlast I just want to suggest  that even the way you handled the logic is not an ideal one.  You need to improve it as well. I can help you in it if you want.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**

Define what the business logic class should do and what it should not:

- As this is pure logic, it should be agnostic of the tag system. You must provide it purely mathematical Models.
- It should send messages to your View Controller when computation is done, or screen should be cleared.

**Step 2:**

Define your Models as raw enums:

```
enum Operand {
    case plus
    case minus
    case times
    case divisor
}

enum SpecialOperands {
    case dot
    case clear
    case whitespace
    case compute
}
```

**Step 3 (In a CalculatorBusinessLogic.swift file):**

Define what the business class should do by providing a contract it must satisfy:

```
protocol CalculatorBusinessLogic {
    var delegate: CalculatorBusinessLogicDelegate? { get set }

    func provideNumberInput(number: Int)
    func provideOperandInput(operand: Operand)
    func provideSpecialOperandInput(operand: SpecialOperands)
}
```

And what results it should send back to your view controller:

```
protocol CalculatorBusinessLogicDelegate: class {
    func onComputationDone(previousNumber: Int, currentNumber: Int, operand: Operand, result: Int)
    func clearScreen()
}
```

**Step 4: (In a Calculator.swift file):**

Implement the contract, move all your logic related attributes to the class:

```
class Calculator: CalculatorBusinessLogic {

    weak var delegate: CalculatorBusinessLogicDelegate?

    var numberOnDisplay: Double = 0
    var previousNumber: Double?
    var currentNumber: Double?
    var currentOperand: Operand?
    var operand = 0
    var isPerformingOperand = false

    // TODO: handle inputs here, fire delegate when needed to notify View Controller
    func provideNumberInput(number: Int) {
        //...
    }
    func provideOperandInput(operand: Operand) {
        //...
    }
    func provideSpecialCharacterInput(operand: SpecialOperands) {

        //...
        if operand == .clear {
            delegate?.clearScreen()
        }

        if operand == .compute, let previousNumber = self.previousNumber, let currentOperand = self.currentOperand, let currentNumber = self.currentNumber {
            delegate?.onComputationDone(previousNumber: previousNumber, currentNumber: currentNumber, operand: currentOperand, result: /* compute result here */)
        }
        //...

    }

}
```

Using [Test Driven Development](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5522-test-driven-development-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started) here could help you handling the complex error cases (wrong operand, division by zero ...)

**Step 5: (In your ViewController.swift file):**

Declare the logic class:

```
var calculatorLogic: CalculatorBusinessLogic = Calculator()
```

Set the delegate in viewDidLoad:

```
calculatorLogic.delegate = self
```

Fire the calculator logic functions whenever you detect related inputs.
Implement the delegate to react to computation results:

```
extension ViewController: CalculatorBusinessLogicDelegate {
    func onComputationDone(previousNumber: Int, currentNumber: Int, operand: Operand, result: Int) {
        lblDisplay.text = "\(result)"
    }

    func clearScreen() {
        lblDisplay.text = ""
    }
}
```

You can read more on how to separate classes in an iOS application by googling for Port Adapters architecture / Clean Architecture.